# nsarray in uilabel

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, uilabel

I want to add uilabels according to mutable array at run time.
actually i have some labels texts in nsmutablearray.and i want to create label at run time and fill the text in label.plz suggest any example or provide guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of NSStrings and you want to create a UILabel for each text you can do:

```
for(NSString *text in myArray){
    UILabel * label  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
    [label setText:text];
    [aView addSubview:label];
    [label removeFromSuperview];
}
```